# S3 API to access Cloud Storage using Service Account with Java

Tags: authentication, amazon-s3, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I want to access my GCP Cloud Storage bucket using the Java AWS S3 API for interoperability, so don't want to use Google APIs in my code. I have seen examples of Basic Authentication using the S3 API when accessing Google Cloud Storage. I want to authenticate via my service account json key ( OAuth 2 ) instead of creating another HMAC key for Cloud Storage. Can anyone point me to a example using Java please. What is the recommended approach - I thought the json oauth 2 authentication is a good one.

Basic authentication goes like this:

```
                // Create a BasicAWSCredentials using Cloud Storage HMAC credentials.
                BasicAWSCredentials googleCreds =
                    new BasicAWSCredentials(googleAccessKeyId, googleAccessKeySecret);

                // Create a new client and do the following:
                // 1. Change the endpoint URL to use the Google Cloud Storage XML API endpoint.
                // 2. Use Cloud Storage HMAC Credentials.
                AmazonS3 interopClient =
                    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withEndpointConfiguration(
                                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://storage.googleapis.com", "auto"))
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(googleCreds))
                        .build();
```

but I want to authenticate with the json key generated for the service account. The service account has access to Cloud Storage Viewer and Cloud Storage Creator.

Thanks

Comment: The GCP recommends the following [ways](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability) for accessing the GCS from AWS S3. Also, I found an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-storage-using-aws-sdk-and-oauth2-1c7764025810#1772) about using AWS Client SDK with GCP Oauth2 credentials for that.

Comment: The first 1 uses the HMAC key, the 2nd and 3rd are for the Command Line and Storage Transfer Service. I was looking for authenticating my Service Account via the JSON key ( OAuth 2 ) using the S3 API.